# How to force browser's autofill list below the Autocomplete List?

Tags: css, browser, z-index, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autofill

So I am working on Autocomplete Address for my website.
For this, I am using jquery's autocomplete method. 
Everything is working fine, but when the browser will give autofill suggestion, my autocomplete list display one layer behind from browser's autofill list.

I set z-index for my autocomplete list but it didn't work.

```
.ui-autocomplete{
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Any suggestion appreciable?

Thanks

Comment: why not disable the browser autofill with `<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />` and just use your jQuery autocomplete alone.

Comment: Hi Sojan, Thanks for the answer. But requirement wants both. Intense behind it is to let the user type minimum detail.